# Flutter - Google Map creation

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am a flutter beginner. Using dart language. I am trying to create a google map in a flutter. My emulator has some problems, so I use Flutlab online.

I have installed packages and all required dependencies.

But when I run the code I get an error "**Target Platform .macos is not yet supported by the maps plugin**".

Also, I'm using my senior's API key, is this causing this issue? Are there any ways to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, **Target Platform .macos is not yet supported by the maps plugin**, seems like you have `mac OS` set as the default platform and Google Maps does not support `mac OS` yet.

So, if you change the emulator to another platform like android, it should work (given you have configured the API key in the respective platform)

To change the emulator, click on the dropdown icon next to the `FlutLab` logo and select any android platform.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! As I mentioned above there are some issues with my emulator. So I use Flutlab online tool. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: Even in flutlab, you can select different emulators. I have updated the answer

Comment: @ Suz Zan - Only a web emulator works. If I select other options, it creates an SDK bundle download link.

Comment: I have not used flutlab before and it seems like you can only use a web emulator. Any other emulator build respective file